Ultralytics YOLOv8 training failed for torch.cat(): expected a non-empty list of Tensors
I am using Ultralytics for YOLOv8. I am getting this error while training the model:

RuntimeError: torch.cat(): expected a non-empty list of Tensors

The images are already converted to 500x500, padded, labelled using LabelImg and converted to YOLO format from Pascal VOC.
model.py looks like:
import os
import random
import shutil
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image

# Define paths
img_dir = r"\location\data\images\train"
val_dir = r"\location\data\images\val"
train_file = r"\location\data\train.txt"
valid_file = r"\location\data\valid.txt"

# Create validation directory if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(val_dir):
    os.makedirs(val_dir)

# Get list of all image files
img_files = [os.path.join(img_dir, img) for img in os.listdir(img_dir) if 
img.endswith('.jpg')]

# Shuffle images to ensure randomness
random.shuffle(img_files)


# Function to clear the directory of all files
def clear_directory(directory):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            os.remove(file_path)
        else:
            os.path.isdir(file_path)
            shutil.rmtree(file_path)


clear_directory(val_dir)

# Split into training (80%) and validation (20%) sets
split_index = int(len(img_files) * 0.8)
train_files = img_files[:split_index]
valid_files = img_files[split_index:]

# Copy validation images to validation directory
for img in valid_files:
    shutil.copy(img, val_dir)

# Write train.txt with images to be used in training
with open(train_file, 'w') as f:
    for item in train_files:
        f.write(f"{item}\n")

# Write valid.txt with images to be used in validation
with open(valid_file, 'w') as f:
    for item in valid_files:
        f.write(f"{item}\n")

print(f"TrainTestSplit completed. {len(train_files)} training images and {len(valid_files)} 
validation images.")


# Check if val_dir contains images
def check_images(directory):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        print(f"Directory {directory} does not exist.")
        return

    files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, f))]
    if len(files) == 0:
        print(f"No images found in {directory}.")
    else:
        print(f"Found {len(files)} images in {directory}.")


# Check contents of valid.txt
def check_valid_file(file):
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        print(f"File {file} does not exist.")
        return

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        if len(lines) == 0:
        print(f"No entries found in {file}.")
    else:
        print(f"Found {len(lines)} entries in {file}.")


check_images(val_dir)
check_valid_file(valid_file)

# Define a transform
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((640, 640)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])


# Load and transform images
def load_and_transform_image(image_path):
    try:
        image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
        image = transform(image)
        return image
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading image {image_path}: {e}")
        return None


# Example usage
image_paths = [line.strip() for line in 
open(r"\location\data\valid.txt")]

failed_count = 0
processed_count = 0

# Process each image
for image_path in image_paths:
    img_tensor = load_and_transform_image(image_path)
    if img_tensor is None:
        failed_count += 1
    else:
        processed_count += 1


# Print summary
print(f"Total images processed: {processed_count}")
print(f"Total images failed: {failed_count}")

training.py looks like:
from ultralytics import YOLO


def main():
    model = YOLO('yolov5mu.pt')

model.train(
    data=r'\location\data\data.yaml',
    epochs=50,
    imgsz=512,
    batch=16,
    device='cuda'
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Where am I going wrong ?

Please add a full error text and the content of the data.yaml file.
